# how to attempt null.value in document.getelementById

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table where it has dynamic rows and I need to get the data and make calculations on it so I get the total number of rows in Javascript and run a loop in it. my table looks like this

```
<table id='mytable1'>
 <tr>
  <td id="name_1">Precious Metals</td>
  <td id="price_1">500</td>
  <td id="qty_1">10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="name_2">Non Precious Metals</td>
  <td id="price_2">200</td>
  <td id="qty_2">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="name_3">Gemstones</td>
  <td id="price_3">300</td>
  <td id="qty_3">10</td>
</tr>
```

and my javascript looks like this

```
<script>

 var counter = $('#mytable1 tr').length;
for (i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
   var price =  document.getElementById('price_'+i).value;
   var qty=  document.getElementById('qty'+i).value;
     var price_calc = price * qty;
     var total_price = total_price + price_calc;     
}
</script>
```

The problem is that if there is one row missed, I mean Admin delete the row #2 and now there will be two rows and when the loop runs and it did not find the row#2 then it throws the error. Please help me or guide me about how should I go with this problem

Comment: `document.getElementById` isn't throwing the error, it's your code attempting to access `null.value` - why not use `$('#mytable1 tr').each` ... then you'll only be accessing rows that actually exist

Comment: You don't have to use IDs. Select the second `td` children of the rows as a list and iterate through it.

Comment: i got that... any idea how to pass the null values in document.getElementById

Comment: Use an `if` statement? `if ( ! document.getElementById('qty'+i) ) continue;`

Comment: since `$('#mytable1 tr')` will return an array-like result that includes only the rows that exist, why would you even need to check if it exists - just iterate through `$('#mytable1 tr')`

Comment: @undefined this works for me

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your HTML and make the calculations independent of the number of rows you have in the table. On top of that, jQuery is not necessary.

Documentation in the source.

```js
const table = document.getElementById("mytable1");
// Put all existing rows inside the table in an array
const rows = [...table.getElementsByTagName("tr")];
// Loop through all rows
rows.map( row => {
  // Price is in the first cell
  const price = parseInt(row.cells[1].innerHTML);
  // Quantity is in the second cell
  const quantity = parseInt(row.cells[2].innerHTML);
  // Calculate total value for each row
  const total_price = price * quantity;
  console.log(total_price);
});
```

```html
<table id='mytable1'>
  <tr>
    <td>Precious Metals</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Non Precious Metals</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Gemstones</td>
    <td>300</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```